# Looking for adjective - classic word for devoid of embellishment

Tags: adjectives

I recall coming across a word in an article that just spoke to me and described my approach to creativity.

The context it was written in referred to a creative piece devoid of unnecessary embellishment, frills, etc.  It might have had its roots in a reference to clothing (no excessive lace, ruffles, etc.).

Does anyone know the word? Two kids in two years, and my brain just cannot come up with it! 
Of course, I should also mention I was a math major, so my word knowledge is lacking.

Comment: **Plain** comens to mind

Comment: _minimalist_ or possibly _utilitarian_

Comment: Ack! @LittleEva minimalist was the exact word I was thinking of. Post it, and I'll upvote.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalism

Comment: @Mari-Lou - good lookin' out, sister!

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - I'm sorry. I left out the "A", an I wanted to make sure you got Binged!

Comment: @LittleEva thanks, you binged me earlier. I replied by upvoting you :))

Answer (score 1):

The words **minimal**-*ist*, **minimal**-*ism* or **utilitarian**-*ist* or **utilitarian**-*ism*, come to mind ...

> **Minimal**: 2. Minimalist (*adjective*): of, relating to, or following a style in art, literature, or music that is very simple and uses a small number of colors, parts, materials, etc.; **Utilitarian**: 2. utilitarian (*adjective*): made to be useful *rather than to be decorative* or comfortable. From [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Is *unadorned* the word you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

"**Unvarnished**" (Collins: "not elaborated upon or glossed; plain and direct  "), or "**pared-down**" (Collins: "with no unnecessary features; reduced to a very simple form")?

Answer (score 0):

Try also:

- Austere
- Bare-bones
- Spartan
- Stark
- Unadorned
- Simple
- Streamlined